# Convert.DateTime throws error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime for "JAN 1996"

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I am displaying a date into a pdf form , the value which comes from:

```
s.getString(UserName, "FromMonth", "id123") + " " + s.getString(UserName, "FromYear", "id123");
```

Which results to this :

> JAN 1996

I tried this code:
String month;
DateTime myDateTime;

```
myDateTime = DateTime.Parse(s.GetString(UserName, "FromMonth", "id123") + " " + s.GetString(UserName, "FromYear", "id123"));
month = myDateTime.ToShortDateString();
pdfFormFields("sample",month);
```

But it gives me an error(refer to the title)

```
pdfFormFields.SetField("sample", DateTime.ParseExact(s.GetString(UserName, "FromMonth", "id123") + " " + s.GetString(UserName, "FromYear", "id123"), "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString());
```

But it also gives me an error , any tips to fix this?

I tried the first code before in some parts of my code and it works , it only in this part the gives me an error.

BDW , I want the result to be like thus "01/01/1996" , which makes the DAY default into 01

Answer (score 1):

`"MM/dd/yyyy"` won't work because you have no day specified in `"JAN 1996"` and the format looks totally different.

Use `"MMM yyyy"` instead. [MMM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) for abbreviated name of the month.

```
string input = "JAN 1996";
string pattern = "MMM yyyy";
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(input, pattern, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: yes, but I want to default the Day into 01 , so result should be "01/01/1996" sorry i forgot to add that detail. @fubo

Comment: then just add `ToShortDateString()` to the `result` from this answer

Comment: I already did in my first code , there are 2 codes that I used. The first one is where I use the ToShortDateString() , second is when I use the parseExact. Which is both generate an error.

Comment: yes , But I changed the pattern into "MM/dd/yyyy" from "MMM yyyy"

Comment: `"JAN 1996"` has no day in it so why do you `"MM/dd/yyyy"` expect to work?

Comment: because I want to convert the JAN 1996 to 01/01/1996 , I did it with the code above before and it works. I tried the code that you've showed but it also gives me an error.